# Add thousands of columns into datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to add very large number of columns into datagridview and I faced a challenging problem. When column count becomes too large the code below adds columns very slowly. This depends upon `size` value - when it less than 10000 I get more or less good result(2-4 seconds to add this number of columns), but when size grows up to 15000 or more the time of adding is not proportional at all, for 30000 of columns it can reach 2 minutes instead of 20-30 seconds as I expect. So my question is it possible to optimize this procedure somehow?

```
datagridview.SuspendLayout();
int size = 10000;
var columns = new DataGridViewColumn[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                columns[i] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                columns[i].Name = "col" + i;
                columns[i].HeaderText = "col" + i;
                columns[i].FillWeight = 0.00001f;
            }
datagridview.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
Array.ForEach(columns, item => datagridview.Columns.Add(item));
datagridview.ResumeLayout();
```

---

And this is what I've done:

```
    int visibleColumns = 20;
    string[] headers;
    DataGridViewColumn[] columns;
    HScrollBar hbar = new HScrollBar();

public Constructor(){
    ...
    int sizeDezired = 15000;
    int size = Math.Min(sizeDezired, visibleColumns);
    columns = new DataGridViewColumn[size];
    headers = new string[sizeDezired];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        columns[i] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        columns[i].Name = "col" + i;
        columns[i].HeaderText = "col" + i;
        columns[i].FillWeight = 0.00001f;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeDezired;i++ )
    {
        headers[i] = "col" + i;
    }
    if (sizeDezired > size)
    {
        hbar.Maximum = sizeDezired - size;
        hbar.Minimum = 0;
        hbar.Value = 0;
    }
    hbar.Scroll += hbar_Scroll;
    ...
}

    void hbar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            datagridview.Columns[i].HeaderText = headers[i + e.NewValue];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: What's your memory usage doing during this period?

Comment: I'm dying to know why you would want so many columns in a grid.

Comment: the problem is you are trying to load too much data into the UI. no person can comprehend that much data at once. I suggest working with the client/enduser and determine what they actually require and what they expect. design the UI around this. if they say they need everything, than they don't know what they need or they need multiple components where each component preforms a specific task.

Comment: I don't know the exact solution, but I remember reading about showing only records that appear on the screen while you scroll.

Comment: The only way I know that *could* potentially speed this up is to set `EnableRowVirtualization=true` and `EnableColumnVirtualization=true`.

Comment: 23 mb for 15000 of columns, job completed in 18.6 seconds

Comment: The columns are shown for days of years, so it could easily become thousands of them

Comment: If it's some kind of calendar you should consider to create different views like outlook(month,week,day) and to show only a limited timespan, otherwise it probably gets useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this code:

```
int visibleColumns = 20;// columns that are in data grid view
string[] headers;// headers for all desired columns 
DataGridViewColumn[] columns;
HScrollBar hbar = new HScrollBar();

public Constructor(){
    ...
    int sizeDesired = 15000;
    int size = Math.Min(sizeDesired, visibleColumns);
    columns = new DataGridViewColumn[size];
    headers = new string[sizeDesired];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        columns[i] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        columns[i].Name = "col" + i;
        columns[i].HeaderText = "col" + i;
        columns[i].FillWeight = 0.00001f;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeDesired;i++ )
    {
        headers[i] = "col" + i;
    }
    if (sizeDesired > size)
    {
        hbar.Maximum = sizeDesired - size;
        hbar.Minimum = 0;
        hbar.Value = 0;
    }
    hbar.Scroll += hbar_Scroll;
    ...
}

void hbar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        datagridview.Columns[i].HeaderText = headers[i + e.NewValue];
    }
}
```

Here horizontal scroll bar added to cycle through all invisible columns and shift column headers to visually "scroll" through all columns(15000 in this example) but in reality only 20 columns are present. This code does not use any databinding, only headers are changing so you need to modify hbar_Scroll handler to show relevant data in cells.

Comment: Nice work, you beat me to it; I had almost exactly the same answer.  One thing to point out is that this technique will work well with VirtualMode, in case there are a very large number of rows, too.

Comment: Cool. Any chance of updating it to handle 'unlimited' rows too? By the way, what advantages/disadvantages would VirtualMode have over this technique?

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are looking for is called pagination.  Look at the following [reference](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/TPeplow/archive/2009/07/14/datagridview-paging-using-virtual-mode.aspx)

> "Paging is a great way to limit the amount of data displayed to the
>   user at one time, but is also a very good way of stopping lots of data
>   being transmitted across the network, being held in memory or big
>   queries on databases...  It solves many problems.
>
> The most common solution is (just like on a Google search) is you get
>   shown a list of pages and you can navigate around pages either going
>   up / down a page at a time or clicking on a page number.
>
> Another way is to make it seem like there is actually one big list but
>   page behind the scenes so the user feels like they are actually
>   viewing one big list.  An example where you see this done is in TFS. 
>   You can do this with a windows forms data grid (DataGridView).